# Calculating double neighbours of a decimal value

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

The code:

```
import java.math.*; 

public class x
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.1);
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.7);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

The output:

`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`
`0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`

This is nice because it lets me find a `double` that is the closest to given value.
But as for `0.1` a value is bigger and for `0.7` value is smaller than real value.

How can I get both values (closest bigger and closest smaller) for any decimal number?

Assume I start with `BigDecimal`, then convert it do a `double` and then back to decimal. I'll get bigger or smaller value. How could I got the other?

Comment: I doubt it's possible if you start with a `double`. By the time your program sees what you've typed in as `0.1`, the value has already become `0.100000000000000005...`. There's no way for the program to know which way it's been rounded (since it can't know the original value). Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nextAfter(double start, double direction)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28float,%20double%29):

```
import java.math.*;

public class a
{
  public static void printNeighbours(BigDecimal start)
  {
    double result1 = start.doubleValue();
    double result2;

    BigDecimal r1 = new BigDecimal(result1);

    int com = start.compareTo(r1);

    if(com != 0)
      result2 = Math.nextAfter(result1, com * Double.MAX_VALUE);
    else
    {
      result2 = Math.nextAfter(result1, Double.MAX_VALUE);
      result1 = Math.nextAfter(result1, -Double.MAX_VALUE);
      r1 = new BigDecimal(result1);
    }

    BigDecimal r2 = new BigDecimal(result2);

    System.out.println("starting:\t"+start);

    if(com<0)
    {
      System.out.println("smaller:\t" + r2);        
      System.out.println("bigger:\t\t"+r1);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("smaller:\t" + r1);        
      System.out.println("bigger:\t\t"+r2);
    }

    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    printNeighbours(new BigDecimal("0.25"));
    printNeighbours(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
    printNeighbours(new BigDecimal("0.7"));
  }
}
```

Printout:

```
starting:   0.25
smaller:    0.2499999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875
bigger:     0.250000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

starting:   0.1
smaller:    0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625
bigger:     0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

starting:   0.7
smaller:    0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
bigger:     0.70000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Math.ulp(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) method might be useful for this, it returns something like the possible floating point precision for the given value:

> Returns the size of an ulp of the argument. An ulp of a double value is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude. Note that for non-NaN x, ulp(-x) == ulp(x).

Here is an example:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1).subtract(new BigDecimal(Math.ulp(0.1))));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.7).add(new BigDecimal(Math.ulp(0.7))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create BigDecimal based on Integer or on String:

```
// String:
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.1");

// Integer
BigDecimal b = (new BigDecimal(7)).movePointLeft(1);
```

It will not give you such results.