# Convert float and double to bit and hexadecimal representation in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double

How can I get single bits (or an entire variable) of a `double` or a `float`?

For example if I have
    float a = 0.5;

I would expect a `String` equal to:
`"00111111000000000000000000000000"`

or in hex:
`"F000000"`

Comment: No. Why? It is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637594/calculating-double-neighbours-of-a-decimal-value . I thought that if I subtract 1 from the binary value, I would get the other value.

Comment: @dcrooney asked because it's good to know whether it's homework because when it's homework we try to be careful with our answers that we don't inhibit your learning :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Java, a float is on 32 bits like a `int`, and a double is on 64 bits like a `long`. Finding the binary representation of these numbers, you need to:

```
float a = 0.5f;
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(a);
String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(bits)).replace(" ", "0");
String.format("%8s", Integer.toHexString(bits)).replace(" ", "0");
```

> "00111111000000000000000000000000" bit representation (32 bits)
> "3f000000" hexadecimal representation (32 bits)

```
double a = 0.5d;
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(a);
String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(bits)).replace(" ", "0");
String.format("%16s", Long.toHexString(bits)).replace(" ", "0");
```

> "0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" bit representation (64 bits)
> "3fe0000000000000" hexadecimal representation (64 bits)

You can check that it works by doing the reverse operation:

```
int bits = Integer.parseInt("00111111000000000000000000000000", 2);
Float.intBitsToFloat(bits);
```

> 0.5 (float)

```
long bits = Long.parseLong("0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
Double.longBitsToDouble(bits);
```

> 0.5 (double)

For the hexadecimal representation, you can use respectively `Integer.parseInt("...", 16);` and `Long.parseLong("...", 16);`

Comment: If the sign bit is zero, it wouldn't be printed!

Comment: @math, could you explain?  Do you mean the sign bit won't be printed, or the value in its entirety?  If the former, yes, `Long.toBinaryString` doesn't print extraneous bits per "This [unsigned long] value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0's", but this is not unique to the sign bit.  You can zero pad the value from the left to get your desired column width.

Comment: As I said, it just won't be printed, due to leading zero. Of course, one could pad this with leading zeros, but the statement above could be misinterpreted in that. And yes, if the exponent has leading zeros as well they will be cut of the same.

Comment: `int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));`

works so it's almost the same code to see the bit string behind a float.

Answer (score 4):

Look at   `Float.floatToIntBits() or  Float.floatToRawIntBits()`.  That gets you the bits as an int.  If you need it as a String, `Integer.toBinaryString()`.

Note, there may be an issue if the HSB is on - you may need to convert to a long to avoid an "overflow".

Comment: The HSB in an IEEE-754 float is the sign bit, unless it's a NaN value, so the sign of the resulting int will be the same as that of the float, with the exception of -0.0.

Comment: Agreed.  That comment was because some of the Java int <-> String code is fussy about the HSB.  e.g. [this stackoverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888946/converting-32-bit-binary-string-with-integer-parseint-fails).  Though I think it's mainly for parsing Strings, not creating them, so that issue might not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printFloatBits(float f) {
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    // Extract each bit from 'bits' and compare it by '0'
    for (int i=31; i>=0; --i) {
        // int mask = 1 << i;
        // int oneBit = bits & mask;
        // oneBit == 0 or 1?
        System.out.print((bits & (1 << i)) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[`Double.byteValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#byteValue()) might help you.

There is also a 32-bit equivalent [`Float.byteValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#byteValue()).

Comment: Byte value just returns the equivalent of `(byte) myDouble`.  It's a lossy conversion.

Comment: **This answer is wrong.** `Float.byteValue()` and `Double.byteValue()` simply casts the number to byte.